# Pop up window stopped giving form information

Tags: forms, popupwindow

I have this pop up window code used in my company's website, and it has been working for the past 6 months perfectly fine, all of a sudden it stopped and I cannot figure out the problem, can someone please validate the code below? On submit, the Search ID is looked for and the information comes up on the pop up window, I cannot figure out what would make it stop showing the information, now it just shows the index.php page in the pop up window....any help is appreciated

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="964" border="0" align="left" cellspacing="0" >
<tr >
<td width="234" height="44" style="text-align: center" ><div class="title2"></div></td>                       
<td width="187" style="text-align: center"><p>
<input type="hidden" name="quicktrack" value="LHAWB_NO">
<input name="SearchID" type="text"> 
</p></td>
<td width="537" style="text-align: left" ><input name="imageField" type="image" src="submit_button.png" align="left" border="0" onclick="popSubmit(this.form);">
<script type="text/javascript">   
function popSubmit(form)   
{   
var popStyle = "width=700,height=675,location=yes,resizable=no";   
var popName = "formPopUp";   
form.action = "http://waybilltracking.com/DCLOG/index.php";   
form.target = popName;  
window.open("",popName,popStyle);   
}   
</script>  </td>
```